# ModelForm save() does not work after changing model

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm playing around with a django-survey from jessykate (https://github.com/jessykate/django-survey) and altered the models.py. Now the save() method does not work anymore and I do not get why that is.

models.py (see comment #)

```
class Response(models.Model):
    '''
    a response object is just a collection of questions and answers with a
    unique interview uuid
    '''
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    # interviewer = models.CharField('Name of Interviewer', max_length=400)
    # interviewee = models.CharField('Name of Interviewee', max_length=400)
    # conditions = models.TextField('Conditions during interview', blank=True, null=True)
    # comments = models.TextField('Any additional Comments', blank=True, null=True)
    interview_uuid = models.CharField("Interview unique identifier", max_length=36)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ("response %s" % self.interview_uuid)
```

views.py (original)

```
def SurveyDetail(request, id):
    survey = Survey.objects.get(id=id)
    category_items = Category.objects.filter(survey=survey)
    categories = [c.name for c in category_items]
    print 'categories for this survey:'
    print categories
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST, survey=survey)
        if form.is_valid():
            response = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/confirm/%s" % response.interview_uuid)
    else:
        form = ResponseForm(survey=survey)
        print form
        # TODO sort by category
    return render(request, 'survey.html', {'response_form': form, 'survey': survey, 'categories': categories})
```

forms.py (see comment #)

```
class ResponseForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Response    
    #   fields = ('interviewer', 'interviewee', 'conditions', 'comments')

[...]

def save(self, commit=True):
        ''' save the response object '''
        response = super(ResponseForm, self).save(commit=False)
        response.survey = self.survey
        response.interview_uuid = self.uuid
        response.save()

        '''
            create an answer object for each question and associate it with this 
            response.
            '''
        for field_name, field_value in self.cleaned_data.iteritems():
            if field_name.startswith("question_"):
                # warning: this way of extracting the id is very fragile and
                # entirely dependent on the way the question_id is encoded in the
                # field name in the __init__ method of this form class.
                q_id = int(field_name.split("_")[1])
                q = Question.objects.get(pk=q_id)

                if q.question_type == Question.TEXT:
                    a = AnswerText(question = q)
                    a.body = field_value
                elif q.question_type == Question.RADIO:
                    a = AnswerRadio(question = q)   
                    a.body = field_value
                elif q.question_type == Question.SELECT:
                    a = AnswerSelect(question = q)  
                    a.body = field_value
                elif q.question_type == Question.SELECT_MULTIPLE:
                    a = AnswerSelectMultiple(question = q)  
                    a.body = field_value
                elif q.question_type == Question.INTEGER:   
                    a = AnswerInteger(question = q) 
                    a.body = field_value
                print "creating answer to question %d of type %s" % (q_id, a.question.question_type) 
                print a.question.text
                print 'answer value:'
                print field_value
                a.response = response
                a.save()
        return response
```

So what happens is when I save a survey I'll get the exact same page with all my input instead of a confirm page.

Any clues?

Comment: It looks like your form is invalid, so when it hits the `if form.is_valid()` conditional it is skipping over it (chuck in an assert to confirm this) and so the save() method isn't even being called. If it is indeed the form being invalid you need to check the form errors to find out why.

Comment: The problem is with `fields = ('interviewer', 'interviewee', 'conditions', 'comments')`. If I add interviewer and interviewee back into models.py and set fields in forms.py it works. Is `fields` required in forms.py?

Comment: "I add this and the problem goes away" does not specifically mean that the problem centers around the line that you add/remove, it's just an indicator of where to start looking. I wanted to know the form errors because without a traceback, they're the most descriptive information you'll get on why the form isn't using `save()`. I will add a more detailed response as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently modifying third party code within your project. The difficulty you're facing is a quick lesson (that we all learn) in why this is a Bad Idea™. From looking at your code you seem to just want to strip off some fields from a `Response` model. A better solution to that problem is to write your own `MyResponse` model and use that, rather than editing the third party app's source.

If you insist on using your modifications (don't insist on using your modifications) then you need to identify why the `form.is_valid()` is `False` (This is a guess, "save() isn't working" is very vague but you haven't posted an error traceback so I'm assuming there isn't one). Your form has errors in it and if you access them:

```
for field, errors in form.errors.items():
    print field
    for error in errors:
        print error
```

Then they will give you a better idea what is happening.

Edit: From the errors you posted you can see where the problem is, you're calling `form.is_valid()` when the form is missing the `survey` attribute, so `is_valid()` evaluates to False and your form's save() method never even gets called. set `form.survey = survey` before you call `form.is_valid()` and see what happens.

Comment: Without answering the questions:
`categories for this survey:
[u'Test', u'Neuland']
question_2
This field is required.
question_1
This field is required.
interview_uuid
This field is required.
survey
This field is required.
[08/Jan/2014 04:57:30] "POST /survey/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4211`

With question answered:
`categories for this survey:
[u'Test', u'Neuland']
interview_uuid
This field is required.
survey
This field is required.`

Comment: Still the same. I thought survey is already passed to form by `form = ResponseForm(request.POST, survey=survey)`